# django-auditlog not working for User model

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, django-auditlog

I am using django-auditlog for creating entries in LogEntry table. my actions for User Model are not getting logged in LogEntry table.

my User model -

```
class User(AbstractUser):
...
...
...

username = None

USERNAME_FIELD = 'id'
REQUIRED_FIELDS = []

objects = UserManager()

def __str__(self):
  return f"{self.email}"

...
...

auditlog.register(User)
```

***I have to use django-auditlog only so pls suggest accordigly**

TIA

Comment: What changes to instances of your User model are you doing and how are you making them?

Comment: Instances like activating/deactivating user, updating first/last names etc.

Comment: In the admin? Have you configured the AUTH_USER_MODEL setting and registered your User model in the admin and de-registered the built-in User model?

Comment: not from the admin panel, but from api level, exactly where I need to change for registering and deregistering AUTH_USER_MODEL setting

Comment: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/topics/auth/customizing/#substituting-a-custom-user-model

Comment: I have registered  AUTH_USER_MODEL in core -> settings.py still no luck

Comment: Can you share your api views and serializers? Are they definitely using the correct model?

Comment: URL - /api/user/activate-deactivate
View - 

class UserUpdate(RetrieveUpdateAPIView):

Comment: Can you add the code for the view to the question

Comment: I am using two different serializers with get_serializer method for partnerships and organziations , which has organziation model and partnership model used

Comment: Can you at least add the code that handles "activate-deactivate"? Does it use `User.objects.update()`?

Comment: it use User.objects.filter(id=1).update(
is_active = True/False
)

Comment: `.update()` does not trigger any signals and so is almost certainly not handled by the package, you most likely will have to log the change manually or update all the records using `save()` in a loop

Comment: I have tried to use save method by first User.objects.get(), and then updating values and then use save(), but still got no luck

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I use django-auditlog version 2.1.1. In my case, I've solved it this way:

```
AUDITLOG_INCLUDE_TRACKING_MODELS = (
    {
        "model": "auth.User",
        "exclude_fields": ["last_login"],
    },
)
```

I hope that it was useful!

Answer (score 0):

choose 1 models.py in any app and import user model

ex. from django.contrib.auth.models import User

then register the user to auditlog

auditlog.register(User)